# How to properly reformat table in aspose after generation?

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

Is there a way how I can apply some custom formating through the code after generation of a table in aspose word?

Answer (score 0):

You can access desired table of Word document and [apply formatting to Table,Row and Cell](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/Applying+Formatting+to+Table%2C+Row+and+Cell). Please check following code snippet to format first table of the document.

I work with Aspose as developer Evangelist.

```
com.aspose.words.Document doc = new com.aspose.words.Document("input.doc");
com.aspose.words.Table table = (com.aspose.words.Table) doc.getChild(NodeType.TABLE, 0, true);

// Align the table to the center of the page.
table.setAlignment(TableAlignment.CENTER);

// Clear any existing borders from the table.
table.clearBorders();

// Set a green border around the table but not inside.
table.setBorder(BorderType.LEFT, LineStyle.SINGLE, 1.5, Color.GREEN, true);
table.setBorder(BorderType.RIGHT, LineStyle.SINGLE, 1.5, Color.GREEN, true);
table.setBorder(BorderType.TOP, LineStyle.SINGLE, 1.5, Color.GREEN, true);
table.setBorder(BorderType.BOTTOM, LineStyle.SINGLE, 1.5, Color.GREEN, true);

// Fill the cells with a light green solid color.
table.setShading(TextureIndex.TEXTURE_SOLID, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN);

doc.save("Table.SetOutlineBorders_Out.doc");
```

Comment: I tested that approach and as for me it's better to avoid adding styles in java and it's better to use word documents for that.